# Can I solve $4x^2 + 7x - 2 = 0$ using the quadratic formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question:**
Can I solve

$$4x^2 + 7x - 2 = 0$$

using the quadratic formula?

**Attempt:**

I used $$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt {b^2-4ac} } {2a}.$$

My answers were $-4$ and $-11$.

Am I right?

Comment: Your answers are not correct. In order to better help you can you please list the steps you took to arrive at those answers so that we can help spot where you may have made a mistake.

Comment: You can check the correctness of your answers [with WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+4x%5E2+%2B7x-2%3D0+)

Comment: And this being your 66th question here, it's not too soon to learn [proper math formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: The formula you used, apart from missing parentheses, is correct, and can certainly be used. We get $\frac{-7\pm\sqrt{81}}{8}$, which can be simplified.

Comment: the sum and product of the roots of a quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c$ are $-b/a$ and $c/a.$ the sumo the roots you have is $-15$ but $-b/a = -7/4.$ so your roots cannot be right.

Comment: I, for one, would appreciate it if you could explain how you arrived at your answers.  Could you show your work?

Comment: You can always solve a quadratic equation by completing the square or by applying the Quadratic Formula. Since the roots of this quadratic equation with rational coefficients are rational, in this case, the simplest way to solve this equation is by factoring.

Answer (score 3):

Your formula is correct. Substituting in $a=4$, $b=7$ and $c=-2$ we have $$x=\dfrac{-7 \pm \sqrt{7^2 - 4(4)(-2)}}{2(4)} = \dfrac{-7 \pm \sqrt{49 - (-32)}}{8}$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: No need to do that to check that the formula is correct. It suffice to calculate directly $4(-4)^2 +7(-4)-2$ and $4(-11)^2 +7(-11)-2$ and to check that both are equal to zero.

Comment: @RobertGreen The comments on the question have already pointed out the poster's answers weren't correct - the answer was to confirm the quadratic formula they're using is correct and a prod in the right direction. :)

Comment: Ah ok, I thought the question was simply "Am I right?" and the answer "no", because $4(-4)^2 +7(-4)-2= 34$ for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may use quadratic formula, and no, you didn't get it right.

By [completing the square](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzm-uhj06q8)

$$\begin{align} 0 = 4 x^2 + 7x - 2 &= 4\Big(x^2 + \frac{7}{4}x\Big) - 2 \Rightarrow 4\Bigg[\Big(x + \frac{7}{8}\Big)^2 - \frac{49}{64}\Bigg] - 2 \\&\Rightarrow  4\Big(x + \frac{7}{8}\Big)^2 = \frac{49 + 32}{16} \\&\Rightarrow x =  \frac{-7 \pm 9}{8}\\&\Rightarrow x =\begin{cases} \frac{1}{4}\\-2\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I try not to invoke the quadratic formula unless I *really* need to. This usually means I use it when I think I will get complex or irrational roots. In your case, simply factoring will do the trick.

The coefficient of $x^2$ is $4$ and the constant term is $-2$. Also, the product of $4$ and $-2$ is $8$. Now, the factors of $-8$ which sum to $7$ are $-1$ and $8$. Thus,
$$
4x^2+7x-2 = 4x^2+8x-x-2=2(4x-1)+x(4x-1).
$$
When we combine like terms, we get
$$
(2+x)(4x-1).
$$
Now, you wanted to figure out when
$$
4x^2+7x-2 = (2+x)(4x-1) = 0.
$$
The answers are now pretty clear: $x=-2$ and $x=\frac{1}{4}$.

---

Of course, your question title asks whether or not you can use the quadratic formula, but, as seen above, it is really unnecessary (i.e., "overkill") to use it in this particular case.

Comment: The root $x = \frac{1}{4}$ is rational, but it is not an integer.  Did you mean that you only use the quadratic formula when you think you will get complex or irrational roots?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig That is *exactly* what I meant--sorry for the brain fart. :)